# Copying text in many files in one folder

Tags: linux, sed, grep

How can I copy text between [START] and [END]? I think sed is the easiest way. I tried use grep but I haven't seen option to mark where is start and where is end.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the input you have, and the output you'd like?  Also, *what* did you try with grep?

Comment: [START]
example 1.1
example 1.2
[END]

in next file is the same as in previous one

[START]
example 2.1
example 2.2
[END]

I used sed -e 's/[START]\(.*\)[END]/\1/' but my console hangs. There are about 100 files in this folder, and text is more than two lines so it may caused this hanging.

Comment: Are you talking about Start and End in lines ?, paragraphs ?, whole file ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` if you mean to say line by line then :

```
# prints with [START] and [END] pattern
awk '/\[START\]/{f=1} f{print; if (/\[END\]/) f=0}' yourfile.txt

# prints without [START] and [END] pattern
awk '/\[START\]/{f=1;next}/\[END\]/{f=0}f' yourfile.txt
```

***Here is example :***

> Input :

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat f
[START] 
example 1.1 
example 1.1 
[END]
a
[START]
example 1.2 
example 1.2 
[END]
b
[START] 
example 1.3 
example 1.3 
[END]
d
```

> Output :

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk '/\[START\]/{f=1} f{print; if (/\[END\]/) f=0}' f
[START] 
example 1.1 
example 1.1 
[END]
[START]
example 1.2 
example 1.2 
[END]
[START] 
example 1.3 
example 1.3 
[END]

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk '/\[START\]/{f=1;next}/\[END\]/{f=0}f' f
example 1.1 
example 1.1 
example 1.2 
example 1.2 
example 1.3 
example 1.3
```

> OR if your data looks like below then

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk '/\[START\].*\[END\]/' f2
[START] example 1.1 example 1.1 [END]
[START] example 1.2 example 1.2 [END]
[START] example 1.3 example 1.3 [END]

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk '/\[START\].*\[END\]/{ gsub(/\[START\]|\[END\]/,"");print }' f2
 example 1.1 example 1.1 
 example 1.2 example 1.2 
 example 1.3 example 1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **sed**:

```
$ sed -n 's/\[START\]\(.*\)\[END\]/\1/p' *.txt
example 1.1 example 1.1
example 1.2 example 1.2
example 1.3 example 1.3
example 2.1 example 2.1
example 2.2 example 2.2
```

with the following two input files:

```
$ cat tst1.txt
[START] example 1.1 example 1.1 [END]
a
[START] example 1.2 example 1.2 [END]
b
[START] example 1.3 example 1.3 [END]
d

$ cat tst2.txt
a
[START] example 2.1 example 2.1 [END]
b
c
[START] example 2.2 example 2.2 [END]
```